# Getting error while trying to connect to SQL Server Analysis Service thru ADOMD

Tags: sql-server, ssas, adomd.net

Error:

> Either the user, 'myName\user', does not have access to the 'Sample' database, or the database does not exist.

I have the `Sample` database in SQL Server and also sample cube in the Analysis Server, however I'm getting the error while trying to run the below code which is just for checking the connection.

```
AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection(@"Data Source=myName\MSSQLSERVER16;Catalog=Sample");
AdomdCommand cmd = new AdomdCommand("SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Sales Count] } ON COLUMNS FROM [Sample] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE");

AdomdDataReader rdr;
int count = 0;

conn.Open();
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (rdr.Read())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        count++;
    }
}

conn.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Count: " + count);
```

Is there anything wrong in my code? or, it is about the security/access issue. However, I have added the myNmae\user as server administrator at Security of Microsoft Analysis Server. May I get some help please.

Comment: Could you share with us your security details for the `user` -  Within MS Analysis Server.

Comment: Well I am using windows authentication for whole thing. Just like to know one thing for Catalog, is it the sql server db or Analysis Server db? Sorry, if the reply is not satisfactory. Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

I ve solved it, you need to add yourself/user in the Analysis Service thru property > security to get access the db. (also, another mistake was using the db of sql server in connection string instead of Analysis server db). Thanks!